# permission denied (public key) error for ssh -vT git@heroku.com

Tags: git, ssh, heroku, github

Installed Git and created heroku account for use with a facebook app 
unable to establish connection with github to clone the files to local windows 7 using the windows Git command prompt: output is as follows:

```
$ ssh -vT git@heroku.com
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Connecting to heroku.com [50.19.85.156] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/User1/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/User1/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/User1/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version Twiste
debug1: no match: Twisted
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug1: Host 'heroku.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/User1/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/User1/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/User1/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/User1/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

This is a debug output any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to add your keys to heroku. Take a look at: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys