# Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, git, heroku, railsinstaller-windows

I've read most of the related issues and tried most of the solutions but nothing has worked for me.

I have installed Rails and Git through RailsInstaller and I'm trying to upload my rails application into heroku from Windows 7 but I keep getting `Permission denied (publickey)` although my keys are uploaded into heroku.

Here is the log of how I've tried uploading my ssh keys the last time:

```
firstname.lastname@LONMAX-LTETB9X /c/Users/firstname.lastname/mytinyurl
 (master)
$ heroku keys:clear
Removing all SSH keys... done

firstname.lastname@LONMAX-LTETB9X /c/Users/firstname.lastname/mytinyurl
 (master)
$ heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: email@yahoo.com
Password (typing will be hidden):
Could not find an existing public key.
Would you like to generate one? [Yn] Y
Generating new SSH public key.
Uploading SSH public key C:/Users/firstname.lastname/.ssh/id_rsa.pub... done
Authentication successful.

firstname.lastname@LONMAX-LTETB9X /c/Users/firstname.lastname/mytinyurl
 (master)
$ git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in c:/Users/firstname.lastname/myti
nyurl/.git/

firstname.lastname@LONMAX-LTETB9X /c/Users/firstname.lastname/mytinyurl
 (master)
$ git add .

firstname.lastname@LONMAX-LTETB9X /c/Users/firstname.lastname/mytinyurl
 (master)
$ git commit -m "first"
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean

firstname.lastname@LONMAX-LTETB9X /c/Users/firstname.lastname/mytinyurl
 (master)
$ git push heroku master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

firstname.lastname@LONMAX-LTETB9X /c/Users/firstname.lastname/mytinyurl
 (master)
$ heroku keys
=== email@yahoo.com Keys
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC...rJqQanPQ== firstname.lastname@LONMAX-LTETB9X
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong or has any suggestions?

Update

Here are some more details on what log i get when i runshh on verbose

```
 $ ssh -vvv git@heroku.com

OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to heroku.com [50.19.85.132] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /h/.ssh/identity type -1
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /h/.ssh/id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /h/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /h/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version Twisted
debug1: no match: Twisted
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.6
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-g
roup-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour1
28,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-c
tr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour1
28,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-c
tr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@open
ssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@open
ssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-ctr,aes192-cbc,aes128-ct
r,aes128-cbc,cast128-ctr,cast128-cbc,blowfish-ctr,blowfish-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-ctr,aes192-cbc,aes128-ct
r,aes128-cbc,cast128-ctr,cast128-cbc,blowfish-ctr,blowfish-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,hmac-md5
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,hmac-md5
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_init: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_init: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 133/256
debug2: bits set: 529/1024
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /h/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 1
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /h/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 3
debug1: Host 'heroku.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /h/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 499/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /h/.ssh/identity (0x0)
debug2: key: /h/.ssh/id_rsa (0xa01a528)
debug2: key: /h/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0)
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /h/.ssh/identity
debug3: no such identity: /h/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /h/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp ac:2f:88:b3:69:96:c5:f4:ba:f6:f6:9d:e6:ea:8f:cf

debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /h/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /h/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have correct repository added? Can you check git remote -v

Comment: I think so, git remote -v  returns back 
heroku git@heroku.com:random-names-3207.git (fetch)
heroku git@heroku.com:random-names-3207.git (push)

Comment: please provide place for `git`, and `ssh`. (usually with `which`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you only have `/c/Users/firstname.lastname/.ssh` your public and private keys `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` (no `id_dsa` file)

Even if your key has been uploaded to heroku, [double-check that heroku `keys:add`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8749399/6309) see your public keys ([heroku key management](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys)), and recognized it already had been published on Heroku side. (And [that it is the right one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22227560/6309))

Make sure the environment variable `HOME` is set at all time to `/c/Users/firstname.lastname` in your git-bash session.

Make sure your ssh keys aren't passphrase protected (at first, for testing) and that you don't have an ssh agent which might get confused with the ssh key used: see "[Unable to push git repo to Heroku, despite valid SSH keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13784348/6309)".

you can also [try and reset the keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18676454/6309).

Answer (score -4):

Git doesn't know where your SSH keys are. You need to put them into

```
C:/Program Files/Git/.ssh/
C:/Program Files/Git/.ssh/
```

or

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/.ssh/
C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/.ssh/
```

only then the Git bash will recognize the keys.

Comment: SSH keys for a user should go into that user's home folder, not into a system-wide folder. As VonC pointed out in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24753535/456814), Git Bash will look for SSH keys in the user's home folder.